# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'. How do I declare an object for a React Axios Get Request?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to use axios to GET data from an API and display it in the view using hooks. I am getting a successful response from the API, but I don't know how to integrate type into the request. The API gives me back an object so that's how I want to declare my response variable (like the 'Gateway' interface below)

```
const Gateways: React.FC = () => {
  
 interface Gateway {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  }

  const [gateway, setGateway]  = useState('');

  const handleClick = async () => {
    axios.get("my/url")
      .then((response) =>
        setGateway(response.data)
      ).catch(error=>console.log(error));
  };

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <div>{ gateway.name }</div> //error is here: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.
 )
};

export default Gateways;
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Gateway is implicitly a string type `('')`, but later you treat it like an object

```
  const [gateway, setGateway]  = useState(''); // string type
 <div>{ gateway.name }</div>  // object type
```

You should consider :

```
   const [gateway, setGateway]  = useState<Gateway>({} as Gateway);
```

also, you are missing one closing div

Answer (score 0):

It takes time to populate the `gateway`, so normally we do

```
  if (!gateway) return null
  return (
    <div className="content">
      <div>{ gateway.name }</div>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, checkout your content-type header in response. I think it maybe is `text/plain`.

If it is `text/plain`, consider using `application/json` instead, so axios can parse it for you.

However, if you can't change the content-type, use `setGateway(JSON.parse(response.data))` to parse the response.data to a JSON object.

Also, start the state without any value and use `gateway?.name` where the state is used. If it's not loaded yet, you won't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

const [gateway, setGateway]  = useState({});

You can either use above format or you can also pass default or initial properties .
This will return an object gateway which is statefull.